# Possible cause for "Can't resolve symbol"?

Tags: linux, lua, cross-compiling

The cross-compiling of Lua, a test module, and a real-life module went OK, but when I load the real-life module on an appliance running [uClinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CClinux), I get this error:

```
appliance::/var/tmp> ./lua -l dummy
Hello from dummy
Bye from dummy
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

appliance::/var/tmp> ./lua -l luasql.sqlite3
./lua: can't resolve symbol '_luaL_ref'
```

I don't have enough experience to know what the cause is, although Google seems to point to issues with shared libraries. Maybe the module expects some library, or some specific version of a library and it's not there?

Has someone seen this type of error before? How could I investigate?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Here are the config/Makefiles that I used to build Lua, SQLite3, and LuaSQL for SQLite3:

```
# cat /var/tmp/lua-5.1.4/src/Makefile
MYCFLAGS=
MYLDFLAGS=
MYLIBS=

export PATH:=$(PATH):/usr/src/baps/opt/uClinux/bfin-linux-uclibc/bin

TARGET_CROSS=bfin-linux-uclibc-
export CC=$(TARGET_CROSS)gcc
export STRIP=$(TARGET_CROSS)strip
export AR=$(TARGET_CROSS)ar rcu
export RANLIB=$(TARGET_CROSS)ranlib
export STAGING_DIR=/usr/src/baps/uClinux-dist/staging
export UCLINUX_LIB=/usr/src/baps/uClinux-dist/lib
export UCLINUX_ROOT_LIB=/usr/src/baps/uClinux-dist/root/lib
export CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -I$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include -DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN
export LDFLAGS= -L$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib -L$(UCLINUX_LIB) -L$(UCLINUX_ROOT_LIB) -ldl -lm

...
$(LUA_T): $(LUA_O) $(LUA_A)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LUA_O) $(LUA_A)

$(LUAC_T): $(LUAC_O) $(LUA_A)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LUAC_O) $(LUA_A)
...
generic:
        $(MAKE) all

# cat /var/tmp/sqlite-amalgamation-3070400/Makefile
export PATH:=$(PATH):/usr/src/baps/opt/uClinux/bfin-linux-uclibc/bin

TARGET_CROSS=bfin-linux-uclibc-
export CC=$(TARGET_CROSS)gcc
export STRIP=$(TARGET_CROSS)strip
export AR=$(TARGET_CROSS)ar rcu
export RANLIB=$(TARGET_CROSS)ranlib
export CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall

libsqlite3.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -o $@ -c sqlite3.c

# cat /var/tmp/luasql-2.1.1/config
...
LUA_INC= /var/tmp/lua-5.1.4/src
LIB_OPTION= -shared #for Linux
...
DRIVER_LIBS= /var/tmp/sqlite-amalgamation-3070400/libsqlite3.o
DRIVER_INCS= -I/var/tmp/sqlite-amalgamation-3070400

WARN= -Wall
INCS= -I$(LUA_INC)
CFLAGS= -O2 $(WARN) -I$(COMPAT_DIR) $(DRIVER_INCS) $(INCS) $(DEFS)
CC=/usr/src/baps/opt/uClinux/bfin-linux-uclibc/bin/bfin-linux-uclibc-gcc
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--trace,--print-map,--cref

# cat /var/tmp/luasql-2.1.1/Makefile
...
src/$(LIBNAME): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(DRIVER_LIBS) $(LIB_OPTION)
```

---

Edit: After being told that it was most likely a linking issue, and after more reading and trial/error, I finally found what it was: When building Lua, the following options are required: "-Wl,-E"

Comment: Providing the command lines for how you are compiling and linking the modules and Lua for the cross-compiled environment would help.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with lua, but in general I can say that when a symbol is "unresolved", this is an indication that the linker cannot find the symbol in any of the archive files or libraries it is told to link together.  You will need to identify what library defines the symbol and include it in the link command, usually with a `-l` flag.  You may also need to provide a `-L` flag giving the directory that includes this library.  In your Makefile, you could add these flags to the `LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I could successfully compile and link the interpreter and the library, so I don't quite understand the cause for that error message when I run the two items on the appliance. I'll investigate the linker part to see if I can find something.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, if you are running on an appliance, you have to make sure that you are not linking against the includes or libs on your build system. Your development system $PATH variable may be pointing to local include files and libs. In addition, you need to make sure that the libs are in a usable location in the appliance, usually in /bin or /lib.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one other reason, when you get errors like can't resolve symbol 'open64' or can't resolve symbol 'setrlimit64' - you might be using an app with the large file support on an environment that doesn't support it.  Watch out for the __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this line:

```
export STRIP=$(TARGET_CROSS)strip
```